# Blood Pressure Measurement

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

When a Doctor measures our Blood pressure, are they measuring the actual pressure of the blood or the excess pressure exerted by the blood against the artery walls?

Comment: What do you mean by "excess pressure", pressure compared to what?

Comment: Excess pressure exerted by the blood as compared to the atmospheric pressure

Answer (score 2):

Typical blood pressure measurements are made relative to atmospheric pressure; i.e. the measured blood pressure is a gauge pressure. The absolute pressure would be the sum of this gauge pressure and the atmospheric pressure.

This is quite obvious when you look at numerical values. A normal blood pressure is about 120 mmHg (160 mbar). A typical atmospheric pressure is about 760 mmHg (1013.25 mbar). Since the blood pressure is lower than the atmospheric pressure, it can only be a gauge pressure. The corresponding absolute pressure would be about 880 mmHg (1173 mbar).